# Errno:150 in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, many-to-many

Have an error in my SQL code, but could not understand, where it is. Please, help me to solve that. Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Records (
record_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
record_year year(4) NOT NULL,
record_quarter int(1) NOT NULL,
profit_tax int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (record_id, record_year, record_quarter),
UNIQUE(record_year, record_quarter)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProductsList (
product_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
product_name varchar(24) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);
```

An error is in that table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RecordsProducts (
recordproduct_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
PRIMARY KEY (recordproduct_id),
FOREIGN KEY (record_id) REFERENCES Records (record_id),
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES ProductsList (record_id)
  );
```

Comment: Please show full definition for `RecordsProducts` table and the exact error message.

Comment: and we should guess what RecordsProducts have?!

Answer (score 0):

- referencing column should be INDEX
- referencing column should have same data type of referenced column
- both referencing, referenced table should be InnoDB

  ```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RecordsProducts (
      ...
      ...
      record_id int NOT NULL,  <=== check data type
      product_id int NOT NULL,

      INDEX(record_id), <===== check INDEXed or not
      INDEX(product_id), <====

      FOREIGN KEY (record_id) REFERENCES Records (record_id),
      FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES ProductsList (record_id)
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB; <=== add 'ENGINE=InnoDB' explicitly
  ```